# Expanding lists

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have spent many hours playing and searching for the answer but no joy!

I have a list that when I hover on it, I want the list elements to expand in width - I have this working, but when the mouse leaves the list, I want the list elements to go back to their original size (this is not a set size).

The CSS:

```
#navigation ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 10px;
height: 30px;
list-style: none;
}

#navigation ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 12px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background: #C00;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">

    <li>about us</li>
    <li>news</li>
    <li>services</li>
    <li>area profiles</li>
    <li>book a valuation</li>
    <li>testimonials</li>
    <li>contact</li>

</ul>
```

The JQuery

```
 $('#nav li').each(function() {
     $.data(this, 'width', $(this).width());
 });

$('#nav').hover(function() {  
    $('#nav li').stop().animate({width:"150px"});
},
    function() {$('#nav li').stop().animate({width: $(this).data('width') + "px"});
});
```

Any help would be great!! I am trying to recreate this menu: http://teefouad.com/themes/truestory/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified a bit your JS in order to target the lis accurately:

```
var $nav = $('#nav'), $lis = $nav.find('li');

$lis.each(function() {
     $(this).attr('data-realwidth', $(this).width());
 });

$nav.on('mouseenter', function() {  
    $lis.stop().animate({width:150});
});

$nav.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $lis.stop().each(function() {
         $(this).animate({width: $(this).data('realwidth')});
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kge66es0/

Comment: I am using your solution - which is cool, however when the elements shrink back to the original size, sometimes the words break - if you look in your Fiddle you will see "Book A Valuation" shrinks to the size of the word "Book" and cuts everything else off. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Tried it in chrome/linux and did not see the issue you just described. Maybe it's a browser compatibility issue and you will need to tweak your CSS a little in order to get it working for all browsers.

Comment: Hi there - OK no worries I will have a play. It is happening to me in all browsers on OS X - blooming browsers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not go for a CSS only solution if the browsers you need to support allow for this? 
If this is not possible - there is no need to store the width before the hover - simply set it to auto.
Here is a CSS only solution, it is far from optimal as it uses min-width, but still - it should be better than the jQuery solution.

```css
#nav {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: min-width 0.5s;
}
#nav li:hover {
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>about us</li>
  <li>news</li>
  <li>services</li>
  <li>area profiles</li>
  <li>book a valuation</li>
  <li>testimonials</li>
  <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with HTML and CSS

**CSS**

```
#navigation ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 10px;
height: 30px;
list-style: none;
}

ul#nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 12px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background: #C00;
}

ul#nav li:hover {
width: 150px;
cursor: pointer;;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">

    <li>about us</li>
    <li>news</li>
    <li>services</li>
    <li>area profiles</li>
    <li>book a valuation</li>
    <li>testimonials</li>
    <li>contact</li>

</ul>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/53Lgo94v/5/)**

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the quick reply. What I need is the animation and also all the list elements to expand at the same time, not just the one you hover over.

Comment: Simple just put hover in the `<ul`a set transitions for the animation

Comment: I made a new jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with just CSS.  Since you are animating from an unknown width, you need to animate `min-width`.  Set `min-width` to 0 for the normal state, and to 150px for the `:hover` state:.

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/427qq4cq/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseleave part you need to loop through your li elements since they all have different stored values:

```
$('#nav li').each(function() {
     $.data(this, 'width', $(this).width());
});

$('#nav').hover(function() {  
      $('#nav li').stop().animate({width:"150px"});
  },
  function() {
      $('#nav li').each(function() {    
          $(this).stop().animate({width: $.data(this, 'width') + "px"});
      });
});
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5v5s0txh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

```
$('#nav li').hover(
    function() {  
        $(this).stop().animate({width:$(this).width() + 30});
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width:$(this).width() - 30});
    }
);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7uw4ao11/)